# Converting a string to dummy encoded variables

Tags: python, r, dummy-variable

Here's the data

```
PlayerID, Characters, Win or Lose
```

I can make it look like this

```
8PYPY0LLQ,valkyrie5 ,  chr_witch4 ,  hog_rider5 ,  zapMachine1 ,  mega_minion3 ,  baby_dragon2 ,  bomber7 ,  skeleton_horde1, 0
```

Or like this

```
2GRG822L9,"barbarians8, valkyrie5, chr_balloon3, fire_spirits8, minion8, firespirit_hut6, rage4, skeleton_horde3,",1
```

The second column is an 8 character combination from 70+ n characters.

I need to encode the variables to be dummy variables, so each character gets its own column. Is there a way to do this in python/R? I'm assuming you have to leave the second column as a string rather than outputting a csv file that looks like this.

```
2GRG822L9,barbarians8, valkyrie5, chr_balloon3, fire_spirits8, minion8, firespirit_hut6, rage4, skeleton_horde3,1
8PYPY0LLQ,valkyrie5 ,  chr_witch4 ,  hog_rider5 ,  zapMachine1 ,  mega_minion3 ,  baby_dragon2 ,  bomber7 ,  skeleton_horde1,0
```

It should probably look like this before dummy encoding

```
2GRG822L9,"barbarians8, valkyrie5, chr_balloon3, fire_spirits8, minion8, firespirit_hut6, rage4, skeleton_horde3,",1
8PYPY0LLQ,"valkyrie5 ,  chr_witch4 ,  hog_rider5 ,  zapMachine1 ,  mega_minion3 ,  baby_dragon2 ,  bomber7 ,  skeleton_horde1,",0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it but I suggest first splitting these 8 strings into 8 columns using the following code:

```
df['Characters'].str[1:-1].str.split(',', expand=True).astype(str)
```

Then use the following code for each of these 8 columns to create dummies:

```
pd.get_dummies(df['your columns'])
```

Duplicate columns for a unique character might be created but you can easily merge them together.